# How to separate front-end and api rules with CodeEffects RuleEditor

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I'm trying to develop a completely separate Front-End, with a Rule Editor.

When I try to declare de rule editor in my MVC, the RuleEditor Builder needs the Rule Object, but I don't have access to this, because is declared in the API.

Is it possible to render the RuleEditor without direct reference to the Rule Model?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing a declared type as your CodeEffects source object you can use Source XML to describe your type. This is more common and convenient way of controlling which of your properties, fields and methods/actions the rule editor should use. Details can be found [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Source-Object-Xml).

Comment: ¿The Source XML, in the element source, needs to reference the .net class and assembly? If i try to reference a class that is in the backend and not in the frontend, the editor is not rendering. Thanks!

Comment: You can set the value of "persisted" attribute to False and value of "type" attribute to an empty string in order to tell Source XML to work with only properties and methods that this doc declares without reflecting any type as its source. For example: <source name="TestName" webrule="4.3.2.6" utc="2016-11-03T20:04:08.9039" type="" persisted="false"> This functionality belongs to the SourceAttribute.PersistTypeNameInRuleXml  property. Details are here: http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Fact-Source-Attribute

Comment: @JonathanSchein Please consider marking this post as answered. Thanks.